# TextView1 can't be resolved to a type

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm trying to finish a tutorial for editable a text declared in the main.xml,

Eclipse says:

> -TextView1 can't be resolved to a type
>
> -TextView2 can't be resolved to a type
>
> -TextView1 can't be resolved to a variable
>
> -TextView2 can't be resolved to a variable
>
> -TextView1 can't be resolved
>
> -TextView2 can't be resolved

here is my code:

```
package marco.prova;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {
    private TextView1 textView1;
    private TextView2 textView2;

    /** Called when the activity is first created.*/

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testo1);
        TextView1.setText("Testo modificato tramite codice 1");

        TextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testo2);
        TextView2.setText("Testo modificato tramite codice 2");
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: awww ..... silly mistakes , we all make those

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TextView1` and `TextView2` are not Android classes, however `TextView` is.
So first fix your variable declarations:

```
private TextView textView1;
private TextView textView2;
```

Then fix your variable assignment and variable use (note the lowercase):

```
textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testo1);
textView1.setText("Testo modificato tramite codice 1");

textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testo2);
textView2.setText("Testo modificato tramite codice 2");
```

Comment: thaks with your help i did it :D

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
private TextView1 textView1;
private TextView2 textView2;
```

to

```
private TextView  textView1;
private TextView  textView2;
```